# Navigating from navigational drawer using Android Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to implement jetpack navigation on my android app. I have created a navigational graph as shown below:

[image: a picture of the Graph editor]

and navigational drawer menu xml as shown below:

[image: a picture of the menu navigational drawers menu items design]

according to the documentation in the android developer site, [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing)

giving the menu items the same id as the fragments or destinations should be enough to ensure that clicking on an menu item will navigate me to the specified fragment. This doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Comment: please post your code from Activity / fragment where you are inflating menus

Comment: I just got this working in my own project, if you still need some help update your question with the relevant code and I'll have a look.

Comment: did you manage to make this work @I_of_T?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque, Yes... see my answer for the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#kotlin), there's a piece of code wiring you need to do:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

or in kotlin:

```
val navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. That should be the solution. I could not get it to work for me because the function "setupWithNavController" could not be found for the NavigationaView class. I was however able to find it in the NavigationUI class. So that's what I used. I then needed to get an instance of the navController, I was able to get it by calling findNavController(this) on the one of my fragment's oncreate

Comment: But what if i am not using menu for navigation view instead of menu i am using recycer view to show menu items. In that case how can i achieve navigation.

Answer (score 4):

**@Dracarys** You should use

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha04"
```

instead of

`implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha04"`

pay attention to **-ktx** part in case if you are using Kotlin. Then you will see     `navigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)` method

**[UPD 1]**

Also, I faced with same issue, when I get navController by calling `findNavController(view)`. Try to use `findNavController(activity, id)` and pass it to `setupWithNavController(navController)` method. It works for me now

Comment: setupWithNavController was missing in alpha02, but is fixed in alpha04

Answer (score 1):

To use NavigationUI#setupWithNavController() you need:

implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha02'

Answer (score 1):

I think standard custom solution is better, as you can handle different menu items with Navigation graph or yourself (like Sign out item)

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.navSignOut -> {
                loginViewModel.logout()
            }
            else -> {
                val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
                navController.navigate(item.itemId)
            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: How do u do this using Navigation Components?

Answer (score 0):

This is the piece of code I added to my one of my fragment's onCreate to make it work. I had initially tried doing this on my MainActivity with no success.

```
val navigationView = activity?.findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
val navController = findNavController(this)
navigationView?.let { NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(it, navController) }
```